# wpf notify changed data in the beackend

Tags: wpf, client-server, wcf-client, business-objects

I currently developing a client server application and use a WCF interface for communication.
Via this interface i get my business objects. I am using MVVM.

The users can make changes in the client (e.g. via a textbox). Later i want to send the obejcts back to the server and the server shall decide whether an object needs to be saved or whether it should ignore it because noch changes were made.

I am now looking for a way to "tag" the business objects so that the server can make his decision.
Has somboody an idea how i could do this???
Or much better does anyone know a tutorial???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is already implemented in the [Entity Framework Self Tracking Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ff407090%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). I don't know if you are using EF in the backend as the ORM, though, you may use some code from the STE T4 Template to implement your own change tracking logic.

Comment: thank you ,
not really what i am looking for but a really good info.

I will implement my own logic :(